# Haskell Cabal update won't work - "Local and remote files match"

Tags: haskell, cabal

I did "cabal update", bumped the version number on my project, and then did "cabal update" again...

```
>cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Skipping download: Local and remote files match.
```

^ The cabal respository changed but the update won't appear without a ~5 minutes delay.

```
>cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library

>ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3

>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
```

Answer (score 1):

Self answer:

They apparently update their package list every 5 minutes or so - you can't make it any faster